# $.extend a jQuery Object in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-widget-factory

When using $.extend on a jQuery Object in the Widget Factory, IE8 seems to lose the jQuery context on the newly created object. Let me demonstrate.

The following code works in IE9+, Chrome, FireFox

```
$.widget("a07.Wooh", {
    options: {
        test: "Awesome"
    },
    _testFunc: function() {
        // Perform some operations on the DOM using this.element jQuery Object
        this.element.after("<div class=\"stuff\">Some cool stuff</div>").next().hide();
    },
    _testFunc2: function() {
        //Copy the this.element object
        this.element2 = $.extend({}, this.element);

        //Perform some operations on the DOM using this.element2 jQuery Object
        this.element2.next().css('color', 'red').show();
    },
    _create: function() {
        this._testFunc();
        this._testFunc2();
    },
    _init: function() {}
});
```

[The working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/SS7mw/)

As mentioned above, this code works fine in all major browser **except** IE8. Basically it returns and error message for the `this.element2.next().css().show()` line:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

The property/methods its referring to are the jQuery methods next(), css() and show()

It looks as if in IE8 the this.element2 has lost it's jQuery context because if I wrap the object in a jQuery function like so: `this.element2 = $(this.element2);` all is well.

[The IE8 compatible jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SS7mw/9/)

**So the question is**, what's going on here? Is this standard behaviour for IE8 or am I incorrectly approaching the situation programatically?

Comment: `this.element2 = $.extend({}, this.element);` - What is your intention here?

Comment: Your fiddle works in my IE8.

Comment: If it works in your IE8, you might have Chrome Frame installed or are in some sort of 3rd dimension compatibility mode? It fails with the same error at the exact line on my local test IE8 and on BrowserStack.

Comment: A for my intentions, I just want a backup copy of the this.element object because I later modify it.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to merely create a separate jQuery object containing the same element, then how about this:

```
this.element2 = $( this.element[0] );
```

Comment: or `this.element2 = this.element.clone()`

Comment: @charlietfl That wont work as it creates a copy of the elements but the reference to the specific DOM element is lost.

Comment: @EasyCo OK.. I looked closer at fiddle. What is point of making a copy in the first place if you want the referenced element in the DOM